# Which is the most appropriate place to include the helper file to make its methods available in integration test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I'm trying to write a test for checking the site layout. In the test I'm trying to access the current_user method defined in the sessions_helper file.

```
require 'test_helper'

class SiteLayoutTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
  end

  test "layout links" do
    get root_path
    assert_template 'static_pages/home'
    assert_select "a[href=?]", root_path, count: 2
    assert_select "a[href=?]", contact_path
    get login_path
    post login_path, params: { session: { email: @user.email,
                                       password: 'password' }}
    get root_path
    assert_template 'static_pages/home'
    assert_not current_user.nil?
    assert_select "a[href=?]", signup_path, count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path, count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user)
    delete logout_path
    get root_path
    assert_template 'static_pages/home'
    assert_select "a[href=?]", signup_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path, count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user), count: 0
  end
end
```

Currently, running the test results in the following error:-

```
NameError:         NameError: undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<SiteLayoutTest:0x00000006841600>
            test/integration/site_layout_test.rb:19:in `block in <class:SiteLayoutTest>'
```

I have included the sessions_helper in the application_controller.rb, as follows:-

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  include SessionsHelper
end
```

I thought adding it here would make it available in the tests automatically. But apparently not.

I'm a rails newbie and am still struggling to wrap my head around the structure of the various modules/classes.

Which is the best place to include the sessions_helper file to make its method available for the integration test?

Also, is there a resource that you could recommend that succinctly illustrates the structure/hierarchy of the various classes in the rails framework? I want to get a sense of how they are all related.

Thanks.

Comment: Try including the SessionsHelper file into your test class.

Comment: I included it in the test helper and it works. Btw, is there a place where I can include it once and it is available everywhere? Right now I've included it in the application controller for it to be accessible in the other controllers and then here in the test helper for the integration tests. It doesn't feel right to me to have to do it two places. You know...with DRY and all. So if it had to be included into just one place where would that be?